# MySQL - How can I detect a day streak in Timestamps

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm currently building an app where the user can track his habits/progression towards a goal.

In the following table, I'm tracking which **user** have been active in which **room** :

| id | room_id | user_id | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 552 | 2 | 2023-10-26 06:48:18.638000 |
| 2 | 552 | 2 | 2023-10-27 08:42:37.852000 |
| 52 | 552 | 1 | 2023-10-28 14:03:59.226000 |
| 102 | 552 | 1 | 2023-10-28 14:16:15.154000 |
| 152 | 552 | 2 | 2023-11-01 17:08:59.649000 |
| 153 | 552 | 2 | 2023-11-01 17:09:37.223000 |
| 158 | 652 | 2 | 2023-11-01 17:15:23.987000 |
| 159 | 652 | 2 | 2023-11-02 08:07:45.183000 |
| 202 | 703 | 2 | 2023-11-04 15:20:10.332000 |
| 203 | 703 | 2 | 2023-11-04 15:20:46.055000 |

My goal is to count the streak of active days for each user in a specific room.

A user can be active multiple time during the same day. To remove duplicate active days, I've used the following script :

```
SELECT room_id, user_id, MIN(timestamp) AS min_time
FROM milestone
WHERE user_id=2 AND room_id=552
GROUP BY room_id, user_id, DATE(timestamp)
```

Which gives me this result :

| room_id | user_id | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 552 | 2 | 2023-10-26 06:48:18.638000 |
| 552 | 2 | 2023-10-27 08:42:37.852000 |
| 552 | 2 | 2023-11-01 17:08:59.649000 |

From this, I would like to count the active days streak from today's date. If the user misses a day, the streak is lost.

What would be the best approach ?

---

**I am using MySQL version 8.1.0**

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? Later versions with window function support may have better solutions than older versions.

Comment: Hi @esqew I'm using the version 8.1.0

Comment: Drop the time component, lag the date column, calculate the day diff, sum the diff. If the sum(diff) > active days, the no streak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways of achieving this, and I am not sure about *"the best approach"*, but here is one option:

```
WITH dts AS (
    SELECT room_id, user_id, DATE(timestamp) dt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATE(timestamp) DESC) AS rn
    FROM milestone
    WHERE user_id = 2 AND room_id = 552
    GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dts
WHERE dt + INTERVAL (rn - 1) DAY = CURRENT_DATE;
```

If we look at the output of the CTE (`dts`) with the `dt + INTERVAL (rn - 1) DAY` added to the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT *, dt + INTERVAL (rn - 1) DAY
FROM dts
```

outputs:

| room_id | user_id | dt | rn | dt + INTERVAL (rn - 1) DAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 552 | 2 | 2023-11-01 | 1 | 2023-11-01 |
| 552 | 2 | 2023-10-27 | 2 | 2023-10-28 |
| 552 | 2 | 2023-10-26 | 3 | 2023-10-28 |

It may not be immediately clear what this means, but if we add the missing three days (`2023-11-02`, `2023-11-03`, `2023-11-04`) to make a streak running back from today (`2023-11-04`), hopefully you can see what is happening:

| room_id | user_id | dt | rn | dt + INTERVAL (rn - 1) DAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 552 | 2 | 2023-11-04 | 1 | 2023-11-04 |
| 552 | 2 | 2023-11-03 | 2 | 2023-11-04 |
| 552 | 2 | 2023-11-02 | 3 | 2023-11-04 |
| 552 | 2 | 2023-11-01 | 4 | 2023-11-04 |
| 552 | 2 | 2023-10-27 | 5 | 2023-10-31 |
| 552 | 2 | 2023-10-26 | 6 | 2023-10-31 |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EBbzFn9z).

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me and create such a complete answer !